# Neo4J: Avoid repeating nodes

Tags: neo4j, nodes, duplication

I have a model with students and the courses that they assisted. All students have a groupNumber.

So when I want to get all the students that assisted to same course but are from a different groupNumber I do this:

```
MATCH (s1:Student)-[:Assisted]-(c:Course), (s2:Student)-[:Assisted]-(c)
WHERE s1.groupNumber <> s2.groupNumber
RETURN s1, s2
```

This works, however, this shows me something like this:

```
Paul | Steve
Steve | Paul
Carl |Steve
Steve | Mark
```

Is there a simple way to avoid showing repeated students?

Comment: Suppose there are multiple Student nodes from the same group helping the same class. Is the result supposed to contain a single random Student from that group, or is it supposed to contain no students from that group?

Comment: I have to get students that assisted the same courses but differ in their groupNumber. The query is ok, all I need is a way to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it - just add one more clause:

```
MATCH (s1:Student)-[:Assisted]-(c:Course), (s2:Student)-[:Assisted]-(c)
WHERE s1.groupNumber <> s2.groupNumber AND
s1.groupNumber < s2.groupNumber
RETURN s1, s2
```

It looks as though your results are repeated because the matches are occurring twice; once in one order, the other time in the other order.   By saying that one `groupNumber` has to be less than the other, it ensures that only one ordering is possible; so for example `Paul | Steve` is possible, but `Steve | Paul` isn't.